# Rstudio Shiny how can I display the version of the Shiny server in the Shiny page?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

Is there a variable or way of querying a running RStudio Shiny webpage to display the version of the server that is running? E.g. display something like `shiny-0.10.1` on the webpage.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can get the version of shiny that is running using `packageVersion`:

```
> packageVersion("shiny")
[1] ‘0.10.1’
```

If you want details on the server you can do a system call:

```
> system('shiny-server --version', intern = TRUE)
[1] "Shiny Server v1.1.0.10000" "Node.js v0.10.21"
```

or if you are running shiny server pro there is a heath check endpoint so calling

```
http://my-shiny-ip-address/__health-check__
```

would return a http response with server info if the server is online like:

```
server-version: 1.2.3.4
active-connections: 8
active-apps: 2
active-processes: 3
cpu-percent: 13
memory-percent: 49
swap-percent: 39.1
load-average: 1.01953125
```

see http://rstudio.github.io/shiny-server/latest/#monitoring-the-server

Comment: Is it possible to create an endpoint in shiny free version?